# What is Java's equivalent for Ruby's singleton

Tags: java, ruby

In Ruby, I can create methods that is specific to an instance (singleton methods)

```
class C;end

v1,v2 = C.new, C.new #=>two instances of class C

def v1.meth
  puts "I am only available in instance v1"
end

puts v1.meth #=> prints -> I am only available in instance v1
puts v2.meth #=> throws -> undefined method 'meth'
```

What is its equivalent in Java?

Comment: You moved to Java from Ruby finally ... :)

Comment: That's.... kind of odd.  I'm ignorant of Ruby, but that's _not_ the Singleton pattern as understood by the rest of the CS world.  I'd call it an instance-specific method (for which there's no Java equivalent).   A *singleton* as understood by the rest of the world is when only one instance of a class can exist.  Does Ruby really change the meaning of "singleton" like that? EDIT: apparently so. That's a terrible practice.

Comment: @CPerkins: I'm not sure what you are getting at. First off, Ruby and Java are different languages. Things work differently between them, that's not "terrible practice", that's just normal. Secondly, the distinction between singleton objects, singleton classes and singleton methods is quite clear. Thirdly, singleton classes *can* have only one instance. Fourth, "singleton" is a generic English word, which means "one-off". That's a perfect description of what singleton methods and singleton classes do in Ruby. And lastly: Ruby is older than Java, so if anything it's Java that changed the meaning

Comment: @JörgWMittag The concept "singleton" as in the pattern didn't originate with Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can do is to have anonymous classes.

```
class C {}

C v1 = C() {
    void meth() {
        puts("I am only available in instance v1");
    }
};
C v2 = new C();

// prints -> I am only available in instance v1
v1.getClass().getMethod("meth").invoke(v1); 
// throws NoSuchMethodException
v2.getClass().getMethod("meth").invoke(v2);
```

In Java 8 you can write

```
interface C {
    void meth();
}

C v1 = () -> puts("I am only available in instance v1");
C v2 = () -> { throws new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

v1.meth();
v2.meth();
```

In natural Java method calls are statically checked and you cannot call a method which compiler cannot determine exists. (You can do this with reflections as above)

Comment: Oh yeah, reflection - didn't think of that to access new methods in anonymous subclasses, thanks for the reminder :) However, reflection is dangerous, and should not be used lightly or maliciously (ie. for circumventing visibility restrictions in frameworks).

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu I agree you should avoid reflections, but also anything which doesn't do static type checking. ;)

Comment: You mean like Ruby altogether? :D

Comment: Ruby is good for some purposes, but you have to be ok with a program compiling but failing due to errors Java would pick up for you at compile time.  For dynamic languages, the answer is writing better test coverage.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like the Strategy pattern to achieve this.  Supply the implementations with a default strategy that throws the UnsupportedOperationException.  Of course this means you can't dynamically add these "singleton method", you would have to create the methods ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in Java, as far as I know!

Answer (score 0):

You can add methods to anonymous subclasses of classes, which kind of feels like that "method is only available in that instance".

That method cannot be accessed from the outside because it is missing in the known contract of the class, but it can be invoked by other overridden methods in that instance of the same anonymous subclass.

This would look like this:

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(){
        @Override
        public int size() {
            if (this.contains("fox"))
                return sizeOfFox();

            return super.size();
        }

        private int sizeOfFox() {
            return 4;
        }};

}
```

You are creating an anonymous subclass of LinkedList which carries an additional method which is only available in that instance: `sizeOfFox()`. This method is invoked by an overridden version of the size() method, whenever the list contains a string like `"fox"`.

The practical use of this is limited and it cannot be truly compared to ruby singleton methods. Most often, this kind of implementation is used when instantiating abstract Listener-Interfaces and the like, and extracting code paths to keep central methods clean.

NB: In Java, a "Singleton" is usually defined as a result of applying the [Singleton Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).